# Issues while doing custom viewcontroller dismiss animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to do simple right to left slide up custom presentation animation but facing issues while dismissing (left to right) it, as modal viewcontroller does the animation smoothly but the container view stays for a moment. How to avoid that?

In my custom animation presenting viewcontroller stays at its place only presented modal view controller animates.

While presenting (Right to left) we add presented viewcontroller to a container something like this. But while dismissing the container stays for a while and then disappears.

```
UIViewController *fromViewController = (UIViewController *)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
UIViewController *toViewController = (UIViewController *)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

//Adding the subviews
UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];
[containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];
```

I tried putting this.

```
containerView.backgrounColor = [UIColor ClearColor]
```

But never worked it's still shows that white background. While if I set it to other color that color appears while dismissing for a moment.

Comment: I don't see you doing any animations, no changing of frames, anything.

Comment: Please, try adding `toViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;` and set `backgroundColor` to `clearColor` and let me know if it helped.

Comment: @Sulthan animation is working fine that's why didn't post the code.

Comment: @FreeNickname Ah got it! I forget to add this line signUpNavigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom; that's why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Ah got it! I forget to add this line

```
viewcontroller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
```

that's why this is happening.